# Internet Explorer 11 PFX File Certificate Export Encryption

Tags: encryption, certificate, aes, sha, des

Hi I have a quick question about exporting my code signing certificate from Internet Explorer 11 as a password-protected PFX file. When asked to set the password I get the option of choosing TripleDES-SHA1 or AES256-SHA256. This is for a Sectigo/Comodo certificate and the representative I talked to on the phone claimed AES256-SHA256 wouldn't work (not sure I believe him...). Is the rep correct? Should I be choosing one instead of the other or does it not really matter? Anything else to know?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So the representative was totally wrong; I just signed my program with a certificate protected by AES-256 encryption. AES is superior to 3-DES so it's definitely the choice to go with and the signing process should be 100% compatible with AES-256 since the protection is for the PFX file only not the signing interaction with Sectigo/Comodo.